# find specific files using "find" command only in top directory

Tags: bash, shell, find

I got one probably silly question:

I'm working on remote server under Solaris using `ssh` and my task is to find specific files in ***directories matching shell pattern*** but ***not go recursively deeper***.

Suppose I have following directory hierarchy:

```
dir-a/
    file-a
    file-b
    dir-c/
        file-a
dir-b/
    file-a
    file-b
```

and I want to find all files named `file-a` in directories `dir-a` & `dir-b` but not in directory `dir-c`. Ok, so far so good - it's really simple with single `find` command:

```
 find dir-{a,b} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'file-a'
```

but the problem is that on this machine installed really old version of `find` so it doesn't has `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` options. I tried to use `-prune`:

```
find dir-{a,b} \( -type d -prune \) -o -name file-a -print
```

but it prints nothing at all cause very first directories in search tree are `dir-a` and `dir-b` themselves so `find` just skip their contents as it actually should. If I could use `-mindepth` I would merely skip this "root" directories with `-mindepth 1` and get another working solution, but as I said I can't. `depth` didn't help also because `dir-a` and `dir-b` are last in find search tree if it used and dir-a/dir-c/file-a is now again in output. 
Oh and this old `find` also hasn't `-regex` and `-wholepath` option so I can't use complex name patterns to exclude deeper files form results.
Do you have any assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using find

```
ls dir-[ab]/file-a
```

---

I notice that [SunFreeware](http://sunfreeware.com) has GNU findutils packages for Solaris.

Comment: yes I could but I suppose to use more complex test than just name equality (for example, date of last access and file type) and do some work with list of finding results then. Example is only for clarity)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:

```
find dir-a dir-b -type d ! -name dir-a ! -name dir-b -prune -o -name file-a -print
```

Here is a break down:

```
-type d ! -name dir-a ! -name dir-b -prune
```

Any directory that is not the name `dir-a` or `dir-b` are pruned.

```
-name file-a -print
```

Then print any other object that is named 'file-a', but then this should be obvious.

I'm guessing that the version of Solaris you are using does not have the `-not` operator, so use the older `!` operator instead.

The drawback is that you will need to add `! -name` clauses for each directory entered on the command-line.  But you could generate a command to set this up more generically.

Answer (score 0):

You may use *grep(1)* to overcome the lack of `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` on the *find(1)* implementation used by Solaris.

Not very pretty, but an easy and fast solution, if you're limited in the choice of software installed (i.e. sitting in front of a customer's machine):

```
$ find . -name test
./test
./test/test
./test/test/test
./test/test/test2/test

$ find . -name test | grep -v '/.*/.*/' | grep '/.*/' 
./test/test
```

You may save the cost of one process by using *awk(1)*:

```
$ find . -name test | awk -F/ 'NF == 3'
./test/test
```